# PHP Not Showing System Files/MAC Files

Tags: php, file, ftp

I have a `php` script that uploads a zip file of images to a folder. This script recursively seeks out only files in the zip file and places all the files in a single directory on the server.

The problem is certain files get double uploaded. This is not the script's fault, but rather, due to the ridiculousness and inferiority of apple computers, when a mac creates a zip file of images it creates a folder of the images and then another folder with the exact same images only it places "._" in front of the file names. So seeing as how we're not going to be blessed with the disappearance of apple computers anytime soon, I tried to include in my `php` script a simple function to search for these inferior mac abominations and delete them from the directory. However, `php` isn't even pulling these files when I use `"ftp_nlist"`.

So my question is: How do I get `php` to pull these stupid things so I can delete them?

```
$contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, '.');

foreach($contents as $key => $value){
echo $key." => ".$value."<BR>";

if(substr($value, 1, 1) == ".") {
    if(ftp_delete($conn_id, $value)) {
        echo "Deleting $value<BR>";
    }
}
echo "<BR>";
}
exit();
```

EDIT:

So thanks to Stephane's suggestion I was able to come up with this which works

```
if($zip->open($_FILES['theFile']['tmp_name']) === TRUE){
for($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++) {
    $filename = $zip->getNameIndex($i);
    $fileinfo = pathinfo($filename);
    copy("zip://".$_FILES['theFile']['tmp_name']."#".$filename, $ezPresenter['currentFolder'].'/'.$fileinfo['basename']);
}               
$zip->close();
}else{
exit("Could not upload/extract file");
}

$contents = ftp_rawlist($conn_id, '-a');

foreach($contents as $key => $value){
$value = explode(" ", $value);
$value = $value[count($value)-1];

echo $key." => ".$value."<BR>";

if(strpos($value, ".") === false) {
    if(ftp_delete($conn_id, $value)) {
        echo "Deleting $value<BR>";
    }
}

if(substr($value, 0, 2) == "._") {
    if(ftp_delete($conn_id, $value)) {
        echo "Deleting $value<BR>";
    }
}elseif(substr($value, 0, 1) == "." && $value != "." && $value != "..") {
    if(ftp_delete($conn_id, $value)) {
        echo "Deleting $value<BR>";
    }
}
}
```

Comment: How do you upload/unzip the files? Wouldn't it be better to prevent the upload/extraction in the first place than to delete the files after the fact (as it appears you are trying to do)?

Comment: Here's how I'm uploading the zip file:

Comment: Can you edit that comment? I assume there is supposed to be a link?

Comment: Yeah, that comment got screwed up. Here's my new reply:

I wasn't trying that originally, but after you brought it up I tried

if(substr($fileinfo['basename'], 1, 1) != "."){ //...continue

And still had the same issue. It still uploaded those mac abominations. I wonder why PHP isn't recognizing files that start with "._"?

Comment: Even searching/verifying by "._" doesn't work.

Comment: "dot"-files are ignored or hidden by default by a fair number of applications/functions. I am trying to get at exactly how you are doing this. What is the complete code you are using? Edit the question please. Code in comments is hard to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`ftp_rawlist`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-rawlist.php) instead.

> ftp_rawlist — Returns a detailed list of files in the given directory

```
ftp_rawlist($connid, "-a");
```

Argument `-a` means `all` as on unix command-line: `ls -a`.

Comment: Thanks @Stephane! That did the trick with a little bit of modifying. I had to take that string and bust it up by the spaces, but that got me on the right route.\n\n
See edits

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue before, but I wasn't using `ftp_nlist`.  What I ended up doing was using PHP's [ZipArchive](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php) to open the zip file and look for (and exclude) the `__MACOSX` directory.  I also ignored zip files where just one directory was inside (so you don't unzip the file and then have two directories deep to get to the data - that always annoys me).

My solution may not be the best for you, as it takes some extra processing, but it worked for me :)

Anyway, without further ado... here is the code I am using.  Hopefully it'll be of help to you:

```
//
// unzip the file
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open($fname) === TRUE) {
    //extract zip
    $zip->extractTo($dir);
    $zip->close();
    //detect single dir
    $basedir = function($x) use (&$basedir) {
        $files = glob($x.'*', GLOB_MARK);
        //ignore stupid mac directory
        $k = array_search($x.'__MACOSX/',$files);
        if($k!==FALSE) {
            unset($files[$k]);
            $files = array_values($files);
        }
        if(sizeof($files)==1 && is_dir($files[0]))
            return $basedir($files[0]);
        return $x;
    };
    //get root directory that has files in it
    $dir = substr($basedir($dir.'/'),0,-1);
    //
    // here I re-zipped the data from the base directory
    // and uploaded this file
    //
} else {
    //delete the file
    unlink($fname);
    //
    // some other error handling
    //
    return;
}
```